# T-SQL split on delimiter

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, split, sql-server-2012

I am working with an employee hierarchy string that is in the format of the following. These number represent `employeeID` numbers and how the are structured within the company, thus being able to follow the chain of management.

```
123|456|789|012|345|320
```

I am trying to take this string of data and turn it into a temp table so I can work with each of the ID's as their own value.

I tried making a function to split the string:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitString]
    (@String NVARCHAR(4000),
     @Delimiter NCHAR(1))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
    RETURN
        (WITH Split(stpos, endpos) AS
         (
             SELECT 0 AS stpos, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @String) AS endpos
             UNION ALL
             SELECT endpos + 1, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @String, endpos+1)
             FROM Split
             WHERE endpos > 0
         )
         SELECT 
             'Id' = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)),
             'Data' = SUBSTRING(@String, stpos, COALESCE(NULLIF(endpos, 0), LEN(@String) + 1))
         FROM 
             Split
)
```

This however resulted in the following:

```
Id  Data 
-------------------
1   123
2   456|7893
3   7893|012|345|
4   012|345|320
5   345|320
6   320
```

Is there a better way to approach this, maybe not needing a function at all or will it be required to achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Turning a Comma Separated string into individual rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493510/turning-a-comma-separated-string-into-individual-rows)

Comment: There are better ways to approach a string split function, yes. [Here](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings) is a good reference. But as for your issue, it can be fixed by changing one part: `COALESCE(NULLIF(endpos,0) - stpos, LEN(@String)+1)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **Without a Parse Function**

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,IDList varchar(Max))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'123|456|789|012|345|320'),
(2,'123|456')

Select A.ID
      ,B.*
 From @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
                      ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
                From (Select x = Cast('<x>'+ replace((Select A.IDList as [*] For XML Path('')),'|','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A  
                Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
             ) B
```

Returns

```
ID  RetSeq  RetVal
1   1       123
1   2       456
1   3       789
1   4       012
1   5       345
1   6       320
2   1       123
2   2       456
```

> **OR with the SUPER DUPER Parse (orig source listed below / couple of tweaks)**

```
Select A.ID
      ,B.*
 From @YourTable A
 Cross Apply [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-8K](A.IDList,'|') B
```

Would Return the same as above

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-8K] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(10))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
    with   cte1(N)   As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
           cte2(N)   As (Select Top (IsNull(DataLength(@String),0)) Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From (Select N=1 From cte1 a,cte1 b,cte1 c,cte1 d) A ),
           cte3(N)   As (Select 1 Union All Select t.N+DataLength(@Delimiter) From cte2 t Where Substring(@String,t.N,DataLength(@Delimiter)) = @Delimiter),
           cte4(N,L) As (Select S.N,IsNull(NullIf(CharIndex(@Delimiter,@String,s.N),0)-S.N,8000) From cte3 S)

    Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By A.N)
          ,RetVal = Substring(@String, A.N, A.L) 
    From   cte4 A
);
--Orginal Source http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/
--Much faster than str-Parse, but limited to 8K
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-8K]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-8K]('John||Cappelletti||was||here','||')
```

> **Edit - Stand Alone**

```
Declare @String varchar(max) = '123|456|789|012|345|320'
Declare @Delim  varchar(10)  = '|'

Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
      ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
From (Select x = Cast('<x>'+ replace((Select @String as [*] For XML Path('')),@Delim,'</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
```

Comment: I like your first version, without the function. I am trying to implement it now. Since I am already working with the source table this data is coming from, is it possible to pass a string to this instead of having it pull from a table? For example, get rid of @YourTable and have the crossApply use a string variable instead?

Comment: @SBB Sure, see EDIT - Stand Alone

Comment: @SBB Seriously, If you are in the market for a parse function, take a hard look at the "Super Duper" option.  Can't take credit for it, but the performance increase was dramatic.

Comment: Hi John, the comment I placed below M.Alis answer would be fine for you too. You might want to read it...

Comment: @Shnugo Sorry, I neglected to thank you for this tip.

Answer (score 2):

If you need a string "splitter" the fastest one available for 2012 (pre- 2016) is going to be found [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/SQL+Server+2012/106903/). This will blow the doors off of anything posted thusfar. If your items/tokens are all the same size then an even faster method would be this:

```
DECLARE @yourstring varchar(8000) = '123|456|789|012|345|320';

WITH E(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))t(v)),
iTally(N) AS (SELECT TOP ((LEN(@yourstring)/4)+1) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) 
              FROM e a, e b, e c, e d)
SELECT itemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY N), item = SUBSTRING(@yourstring, ((N*4)-3), 3) 
FROM iTally;
```

Results:

```
itemNumber           item
-------------------- ----
1                    123
2                    456
3                    789
4                    012
5                    345
6                    320
```

I write more about this and provide examples of how to put this logic into a function [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/set-based/141507/).

Answer (score 1):

I use this version of the Split function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split]
(
  @delimited nvarchar(max),
  @delimiter nvarchar(100)
) RETURNS @t TABLE
(
-- Id column can be commented out, not required for sql splitting string
  id int identity(1,1), -- I use this column for numbering splitted parts
  val nvarchar(max)
)
AS
BEGIN
  declare @xml xml
  set @xml = N'<root><r>' + replace(@delimited,@delimiter,'</r><r>') + '</r></root>'

  insert into @t(val)
  select
    r.value('.','varchar(max)') as item
  from @xml.nodes('//root/r') as records(r)

  RETURN
END
```

You Query would look something like....

```
SELECT * 
FROM TableName t 
  CROSS APPLY [dbo].[Split](t.EmpIDs, '|')
```

Comment: You might think about the following enhancement: `replace((SELECT @delimited AS [*] FOR XML PATH('')),@delimiter,'</r><r>')`. Doing so, your function would be able to split strings containing forbidden characters. Otherwise your function would break with `SELECT * FROM dbo.Split('this,is,<test>,for,< & >',',')`

Comment: Btw: with this enhancement all forbidden characters are turned into their entities (e.g. `&lg;`). That means, that - if you delimiter was the semicolon or the ampersand - you could get into troubles again. One way is to replace the delimiter first with something else, do the encoding trick and use the replacement value for the split...